# Biber: shorthands with macros \textbf{} get sorted differently

Tags: biblatex, biber

If I change a shorthand in the `.bib` file from `XYZ` to `\textbf{X}YZ` the order in the bibliography changes.

How can I have shorthands where some of the shorthands start with a `\textbf` (to bold-font certain letters) without distorting the sorting order?

---

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
        style=alphabetic,
        natbib=true,
        sorting=ynt,
        ]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{xei2016asdf,
Author = {Xei, A and A, B and B, C and C, D},
Title = {asdf is asdf},
Year = {2016},
}
@article{xei2017bob,
Author = {Xei, A and A, B and B, C and C, D},
Title = {bob is bob},
Year = {2017},
}
@article{xei2017bob2,
Author = {Xei, A and A, B and B, C and C, D},
Title = {bob is bob 2},
Year = {2017},
shorthand = {\textbf{X}ei+17},
sortshorthand = {Xei+17},
}
@article{xei2017alice,
Author = {Xei, A and A, B and B, C},
Title = {alice is alice},
Year = {2017},
}
@article{xei2018alice2,
Author = {Xei, A and A, B and B, C},
Title = {alice is alice 2},
Year = {2018},
shorthand = {\textbf{X}AB18},
sortshorthand = {XAB18},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\newrefcontext[sorting=anyvt]
\cite{xei2016asdf,xei2017bob,xei2017bob2,xei2017alice,xei2018alice2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Results in the bibliography:
[image]

But I'd like the following sorting still:
[image]

---

There is one curiosity about the proposed solution.
If one considers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
        style=alphabetic,
        ]{biblatex}

\DeclareSortingScheme{anyt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortshorthand}
    \field{labelalpha}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{volume}
    \literal{0}
  }
}

\DeclareSortingScheme{anyvt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortshorthand}
    \field{labelalpha}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{volume}
    \literal{0}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{xei2016asdf,
Author = {Xei, A and A, B and B, C and C, D},
Title = {asdf is asdf},
Year = {2016},
}
@article{xei2018bob,
Author = {Xei, A and A, B and B, C and C, D},
Title = {bob is bob},
Year = {2018},
}
@article{xei2017bob2,
Author = {Xei, A and A, B and B, C and C, D},
Title = {bbob is bob 2},
Year = {2017},
shorthand = {\textbf{X}ei+17},
sortshorthand = {Xei+17},
}
@article{xei2017alice,
Author = {Xei, A and A, B and B, C},
Title = {alice is alice},
Year = {2017},
}
@article{xei2018alice2,
Author = {Xei, A and A, B and B, C},
Title = {alice is alice 2},
Year = {2018},
shorthand = {\textbf{X}AB18},
sortshorthand = {XAB18},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{xei2016asdf,xei2018bob,xei2017bob2,xei2017alice,xei2018alice2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

we get[image]

versus the ordering w/o shorthands[image]

Comment: The second MWE produces https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxhUt.png for me. So I'm going to assume this is causes by a `biblatex` or Biber bug in your outdated version that has since been resolved.

Comment: Chrmpf...that is unfortunate

Comment: This then seems something that cannot be resolved or worked around w/o somehow updating the biblatex version...

Comment: Well, it might be possible to find a work-around, but there have been many changes since the version you use was released and it would be time consuming to track the issue through the versions since then. And it is not guaranteed that it is possible to find a workable alternative (especially if the issue is on the Biber side).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`biblatex` knows the field `sortshorthand`. The [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) explains (§2.2.3 *Special Fields*, p. 30):

> [`sortshorthand`] Similar to `sortkey` but used in the list of shorthands. If present, `biblatex` uses
>   this field instead of `shorthand` when sorting the list of shorthands. This is useful if
>   the shorthand field holds shorthands with formatting commands such as `\emph` or `\textbf`.

For the `alphabetic` sorting schemes `anyt` and `anyvt` `biblatex` does not use `sortshorthand` (as that would bascially mean keeping track of a `labelalpha` and a `sortlabelalpha` that would be built according to the same rules, but gives precedence to `sort...` fields).

With the standard settings (which set `labelalpha` to `shorthand` if the latter exists), it is enough to add `\field{sortshorthand}` before `\field{labelalpha}` in the sorting schemes.

The MWE redefines both sorting schemes, but if you only use one of the two you can drop the other one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
        style=alphabetic,
        ]{biblatex}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{anyt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortshorthand}
    \field{labelalpha}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{volume}
    \literal{0}
  }
}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{anyvt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortshorthand}
    \field{labelalpha}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{volume}
    \literal{0}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{xei2016asdf,
Author = {Xei, A and A, B and B, C and C, D},
Title = {asdf is asdf},
Year = {2016},
}
@article{xei2017bob,
Author = {Xei, A and A, B and B, C and C, D},
Title = {bob is bob},
Year = {2017},
}
@article{xei2017bob2,
Author = {Xei, A and A, B and B, C and C, D},
Title = {bob is bob 2},
Year = {2017},
shorthand = {\textbf{X}ei+17},
sortshorthand = {Xei+17},
}
@article{xei2017alice,
Author = {Xei, A and A, B and B, C},
Title = {alice is alice},
Year = {2017},
}
@article{xei2018alice2,
Author = {Xei, A and A, B and B, C},
Title = {alice is alice 2},
Year = {2018},
shorthand = {\textbf{X}AB18},
sortshorthand = {XAB18},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{xei2016asdf,xei2017bob,xei2017bob2,xei2017alice,xei2018alice2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sorting order [XAB17], [XAB18], [Xei+16], [Xei+17], [Xei+17]]

Comment: Hm, this sounds very much like what I need. It seems it doesn't work, however. I am unsure what the problem is. I am using biblatex, backend=biber, natbib=true, style=alphabetic, sorting=ynt (trying to list the relevant options here). If I compile without adding a shorthand, the bib is sorted fine by ynt, XY+13 before XY+14 etc. Once I add `shorthand={\textbf{X}Y+14}` the order of those two entries changes, adding `sortshorthand={XY+14}` does not help.

Comment: @hugolugo If it does not work, please show us an example document, a so-called MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that shows what you are doing.

Comment: @hugolugo Ah, I see you edited the comment with a bit more info after I asked for the MWE. Please consider adding those *crucial* bits of information to your question and please also consider adding a full MWE in the sense of the two links above. I'm a bit confused because `sorting=ynt` should mean that the `shorthand` is not used for sorting at all (only year, name and title are relevant).

Comment: Ah, sorry about that! Yeah, that is what I am also confused about. It is a bit difficult to compile a MWE since starting from scratch I won't encounter that problem, so it's probably some weird interaction of things. Douh.

Comment: @hugolugo You don't have to start from scratch. You can take a copy of your current document that reproduces the issue and remove superfluous stuff until the problem is isolated. With the binary search method (comment out half of the code, see if the issue persists, if not add the deleted half back in and delete the other half, repeat) it should be possible to reduce even large documents in a reasonable amount of time. There are many things that are unlikely to play a role here (the text of your document, non-bib-related packages), so with a bit of luck you can easily remove a lot.

Comment: @hugolugo Are you sure it is even the `shorthand`'s fault? Maybe you also have a `\textbf` in another field that *is* relevant for sorting (the use case looks a bit like you are trying to highlight a particular name, if you also said something like `author = {Anne Elk and \textbf{Emma Sigfridsson} and Ulf Ryde}`, then that could explain the issue at hand and `shorthand` would not be the culprit).

Comment: `\newrefcontext[sorting=anyvt]` seems to be the problem :-) Still in the process of tracking it down. Removing the `a` order does not change when adding the shorthand anymore, however, the order with `a` was preferred :D

Comment: Aha, sorting after label is what I'd prefer (first author's last name, year, name). That uses the label field of the bibentries if available and otherwise the generated label. However, sortlabel or something similar is not available..

Comment: @hugolugo Then you should be able to reproduce the issue if you remove the `\newrefcontext` and the `sorting=ynt` from the loading options. `style=alphabetic` automatically sets the sorting scheme `anyt`, which should be close enough here, I guess.

Comment: While this is true. I feel the bibliography should be sorted by key so that it is easier to find entries, sometimes the nyt sorting does not agree with the label sorting. Having anyt as sorting, again the shorthand will screw the order..

Comment: @hugolugo Mhh, yes. I'm not trying to push you to adapt a certain sorting style in your document (I personally think that `anyt` [the default] or `anyvt` is the sensible sorting for an `alphabetic` style, but sorting alphabetic styles is *tricky* since people may expect different things based on their previous knowledge). The comment was just to help you to come up with a more compact example (MWE-wise) so I can investigate the issue properly.

Comment: I've added a MWE, hope it's ok :-)

Comment: @hugolugo Absolutely. As mentioned above, it could be *tad* more minimal by removing the `\newrefcontext[sorting=anyvt]` and the `sorting=nyt` option to obtain the `alphabetic` default sorting, which would also reproduce the issue, but that hardly matters.

Comment: Ah, good point, that could be simplified further, thanks! I am getting `undefined control sequence DeclareSortingTemplate` am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `DeclareSortingScheme` works for me

Comment: @hugolugo The command was renamed from `\DeclareSortingScheme` to `\DeclareSortingTemplate` in `biblatex` v3.8 (2017-11-04), so that means you are using a version of `biblatex` that is older than two years (v3.7 is from 2016-12-08).

Comment: I cannot change that unfortunately as I am only allowed at corporate to use what is in the ubuntu repos // There is one more curiosity, if you consider
```
@article{xei2017bob2,
Author = {Xei, A and A, B and B, C and C, D},
Title = {bbob is bob 2},
Year = {2017},
shorthand = {\textbf{X}ei+17},
sortshorthand = {Xei+17a},
}
```
Then the order with shorthands is different from what one would expect.

Comment: To clarify that it's not about the appended `a` if there are multiple entries for one year, the following is even better, I'll add it to the original Q.